# Primefactors in F#

Tags: algorithm, f#

I am trying to learn F#.
I wrote a function that factors out primes.

```
let PrimeFactors x =
  let rec PrimeFactorsRecursive x div list =
     if x % div = 0 then PrimeFactorsRecursive (x/div) div list @ [div]
     elif div > int(System.Math.Sqrt(float(x))) then 
       if x > 1 then list @ [x]
       else list
     else PrimeFactorsRecursive x (div + 1) list
  PrimeFactorsRecursive x 2 []
```

Now I am unsure if this is a good F# function or if it is more like "c#, written in f#".

Is there a "more" functional way to write this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primal problem in your code is that you use `@` to concat two lists. Concating two lists costs linear time, not constant time.

The constant way is to add the new prime number to the head of a list using `::` operator as shown below:

```
let primeFactors x = 
    let rec fact x div list = 
        if x % div = 0 then
            fact (x/div) div (div::list)
        elif div > int(sqrt (float x)) then
            if x > 1 then x::list
            else list
        else
            fact x (div+1) list
    fact x 2 []
```

Also `let` bind values are usually following camleStyle naming conversions.

Comment: Agree that seeing `@` is a code smell of the novice F# programmer.

Comment: Thanks. (div::list) was still missing in my repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

Another "improvement" not yet mentioned is to use piping so that instead of

```
int(System.Math.Sqrt(float(x)))
```

you have

```
(x |> float |> sqrt |> int)
```

Comment: An while I am not sure if it add to cleanness writing it like this, it certainly looks nice!

Comment: In F#, piping is typically favored over nested function calls. Often times for practical reasons since the F# compiler performs type inference in a rigid left-to-right fashion. But it's also a matter of style, where piping lets you view transformations of an input as a series of steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use guarded patterns to reduce the if-expression nesting.  Other than that it looks like perfectly reasonable idiomatic functional code to me.